# Remapping in ByteBuddy Advice classes

Tags: byte-buddy

ByteBuddy has `net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.commons.Remapper` which allows e.g. runtime shading by using a classloader which transforms and remaps classes during loading. But I have a problem with remapping type references in ByteBuddy `Advice` classes. I assume it happens because BB does not actually load them as classes, but merely uses `getResourceAsStream` or similar to get byte array of the `Advice` class files.

So, question: how can I supply a `Remapper` for `Advice` classes?

Answer (score 0):

You think about locating advice classes? You can supply an optional argument of type `ClassFileLocator` which is responsible for finding a class file for a given class. You'd need to look up a *.class* file with a different name or write a delegator that adjusts the class name before passing on to a different class file locator.

Comment: No, not about locating. My advice method calls some method and I have to change/relocate/remap the type of the returned value of that method call.

Comment: I see. You'd need to register a MemberSubstitution for this.

Comment: Thanks Rafael :) Is there some example of using that? Especially for an use-case similar to remapping/shading?

Comment: If you look into GitHub, you can find it being applied in the tests: MemberSubstitutionTest. It's however more appropriate for actual changes. I think shading might better be adressed by registering a remapper via a AsmClassVisitorWrapper.